# Django how to change admin urls?

Tags: django, file, url, upload, admin

i have a problem. In my project i am uploading file, it gets saved perfectly fine. It is accessible. I save it to the static/assets/uploaded files, ten generate the name: time + original filename.

But in django admin page i can't access it:
(link that admin page gives me)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/project/minipost/4/uploaded_files/1428326830_08_name.pdf/
```

The correct url would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/uploaded_files/1428326830_08_name.pdf/
```

I have no idea how do i change or redirect or whatever the admin generated link to the correct one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of your `MEDIA_URL` setting?

Comment: hello @DanielRoseman my MEDIA_URL is not set to anything

Comment: is MEDIA_URL somehow connected to  my problem?

Comment: Well yes; it defines the URL that media is served at. If you don't define it, your file will be shown with a relative URL, which is why you're seeing an admin URL from the admin. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).

Comment: Hm, @DanielRoseman i dont seem to understand what is wrong now. 
my `MEDIA_ROOT` is `MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/paulius/django-paulius/epc/static/'`

so do i set my MEDIA_URL to `'/static' ` ?

Comment: if i do then i get error that it is the save value as `'STATIC_URL'` and uploaded_files directory is not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed `MEDIA_URL`

I just had to set it correctly:

`MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/work/django-work/workproject/static/'`

`MEDIA_URL = '/static/assets/'`